# How to print a reversed colorbar in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to reverse a colorbar on a figure saved as a pdf from Matlab. I can reverse the colorbar on my screen, but when I print my figure as a pdf the colorbar is flipped back to the normal direction again.

Minimum example:

```
figure(1)
colormap(parula(100))
c = colorbar('direction','reverse');
print(1,'-dpdf','graphs\test_colorbar.pdf',sprintf('-r%d',150))
```

Using export_fig does not help - when export_fig prints a reversed colorbar it flips the colormap and reverses the label order, which does not work if the ticks are not symmetric around the middle value of the colorbar.

Minimum example showing why flipping the colorbar and labels does not help:

```
tick_array = 0:0.3:1;

figure(1)
colormap(parula(100))
colorbar('direction','reverse','Ticks',tick_array)
export_fig('graphs\test_colorbar.pdf','-pdf')

tick_labels = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(flip(tick_array)')));

figure(2)
colormap(flipud(parula(100)))
colorbar('Ticks',tick_array,'Ticklabels',tick_labels)
```

The figure saved by export_fig looks like figure 2 (which is incorrect).

Answer (score 4):

Try reversing the map itself, instead of the parameter that control its direction:

```
figure(1)
c = parula(100);
colormap(flipud(c));
colorbar;
print(1,'-dpdf','graphs\test_colorbar.pdf',sprintf('-r%d',150))
```

---

I also really suggest `export_fig` for saving images in MATLAB, especially for publication quality figures

Comment: I could reverse the colormap (and also the labels) as a workaround. However, that doesn't explain why printing the figure has the colorbar in the opposite direction as on the screen. Also, that fix only works if the colorbar is the last thing I plot (I think).

Comment: @tannoreth the answer is "because `print` sucks", unfortunately. That is the reason `export_fig` is the N1 all time downloaded file for MATLAB. `print` works for basic things, but it is very limited and has tons of errors

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix doesn't work for some of my graphs where the labels aren't symmetric (e.g. if the colormap goes from 0 to 1.2, but the labels only go from 0 to 1). I will check out export-fig.

Comment: Export_fig prints the figure by reversing the colormap and the order of the labels (which does not work with some of my figures).

Comment: @tannoreth if you genuinely found a bug in `export_fig` you should report it in Github. Yari Altmani does generally fix them quite quick.